# How to create nested stacknavigators in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-v5

I want to create my file system as :
AppStackNavigator.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';

import PropertyAndGuestScreen from '../screens/PropertyAndGuest/PropertAndGuestScreen';
import LocationScreen from '../screens/LocationScreen';
import AmenitiesScreen from '../screens/AmentiesScreen';
import TitleScreen from '../screens/TitleScreen';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const PropertyAndGuestStack = () => {
  <Stack.Navigator
    screenOptions={{
      headerShown: false,
    }}>
    <Stack.Screen name="PropertyAndGuest" component={PropertyAndGuestScreen} />
  </Stack.Navigator>;
};

const LocationStack = () => {
  <Stack.Navigator
    screenOptions={{
      headerShown: false,
    }}>
    <Stack.Screen name="Location" component={LocationScreen} />
  </Stack.Navigator>;
};

const AmenitiesStack = () => {
  <Stack.Navigator
    screenOptions={{
      headerShown: false,
    }}>
    <Stack.Screen name="Amenity" component={AmenitiesScreen} />
  </Stack.Navigator>;
};

const TitleStack = () => {
  <Stack.Navigator
    screenOptions={{
      headerShown: false,
    }}>
    <Stack.Screen name="Title" component={TitleScreen} />
  </Stack.Navigator>;
};

const AppStackNavigator = () => {
  <Stack.Navigator
    screenOptions={{
      headerShown: false,
    }}>
    <Stack.Screen
      name="PropertyAndGuestStack"
      component={PropertyAndGuestStack}
    />
    <Stack.Screen name="LocationStack" component={LocationStack} />
    <Stack.Screen name="AmenitiesStack" component={AmenitiesStack} />
    <Stack.Screen name="TitleStack" component={TitleStack} />
  </Stack.Navigator>;
};

export default AppStackNavigator
```

then I have
AppNavigator.js where am calling the AppStackNavigator.js

```
import * as React from 'react'
import AppStackNavigator from './AppStackNavigator';
import ListScreen from '../screens/ListScreen';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const AppNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: null,
      }}>
      <Stack.Screen name="List" component={ListScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="AppStackNavigator" component={AppStackNavigator} />

    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

export default AppNavigator
```

and lastly, I have App.js where
I want to call AppNavigator.js

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import * as React from 'react';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import AppNavigator from './src/navigation/AppNavigator';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <AppNavigator />
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
  }
}
```

However, when I finally try to navigate to a certain page as PropertandGuest like

```
this.props. navigation.navigate('PropertyAndGuest')
```

It says that the screen does not exist, however you could clearly see in the above code that the screen does exist. And I want to create separate stack for each because there are many more screens to be added to individual stack.
The error is as follows:

```
 The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"PropertyAndGuest"} was not handled by any navigator.

Do you have a screen named 'PropertyAndGuest'?
```

Kindly let me know where am going wrong? And do let mw know if anything else is required for better understanding. Thank you.

Comment: In AppStackNavigator.js, you need to create separate stack-navigators for each of them. for example, 
const locationStack = createStackNavigator(); const AmenitiesStack = createStackNavigator(); and so on. For more information, have a look at this https://reactnavigation.org/docs/screen-options-resolution

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass 2 parameters to `navigate` function. First one should be name of the Root and second one is an object which is included `screen` property and `params` property with name of screen that you want to shown up and also `Stack.Navigator` should be returned from the functions.

Try this,

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('AppStackNavigator',{ screen: 'PropertyAndGuestStack', params: {
screen: 'PropertyAndGuest', })
```

Note : If you have not provided more than one screen in your stack then just call with the root name.

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('AppStackNavigator')
```

read the docs.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/

Comment: I added some changes now all done go through the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

have fixed the above bug, thanks to @Chandradeepta, you need to create stack navigators for all the screens and then nest them, which I was not doing and also every stack function has to be returned.